# Is it possible to let capybara/webdriver start firefox minimized/unfocused?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, cucumber, capybara, webdriver

Is it possible to stop Firefox from popping up when cucumber hits a @javascript tag? After a while it gets frustrating to always get disrupted while running tests.

It would be nice if webdriver was to start Firefox minimized or not focus on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no API in WebDriver to do this, and it's not really advisable since Firefox won't trigger certain events (like focus, blur) when the window is in the background. I usually work around this by using a virtual machine (e.g. in VirtualBox) or a separate X display.

Answer (score 0):

You can add lines below to Info.plist of Firefox.app. After that it will start without grabbing focus.

```
<key>LSBackgroundOnly</key>
<string>1</string>
```

Comment: where i am supposed to find this file in windows7?